# Selenium not sending spacebars to application

Tags: ajax, selenium

I am using Selenium IDE 2.8.

I am a tester and using firefox to test a php based application with ajax.

There is a point in the application where three space bars are entered into the textfield and ajax will fetch all data and display a seperate bit of css displaying the information.

Enter 3 spaces in the textfield, information then appears.

For some reason on playback this 'three space bar key press' event isn't called or indeed reaches the texfield....nothing happens, ajax has nothing to do and the info that my selenium script is waiting for doesn't appear and promptly fails.

There is nothing to 'waifFor...' etc.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sendKeys` command instead of `type`

Comment: if the IDE is anything similar to the RC/WebDriver bindings, then Surya is correct.  use `sendKeys`